# When using pyTrends, I get the following error: TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'google_username' and 'google_password'

Tags: python

Error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3034775b0776> in <module>
      6 # Create a Google Trend Object
      7 
----> 8 totalTrend = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)
      9 
     10 # Declare a var to store the search term

TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'google_username' and 'google_password'
```

I do not know where I can enter my google username and google password in order to properly access gTrends.

Answer (score 0):

from the documnentation/example it seems you need to initialize connection and login first

```
# Login to Google. Only need to run this once, the rest of requests will use the same session.
pytrend = TrendReq()

# Get Google Hot Trends data

today_searches_df = pytrend.today_searches()
print(today_searches_df.head())
```

Comment: Dear Chris, thank you.
But I am already doing this. My question is: Where, at which position can I enter my google password and google username to login to google?
Just doing pytrend = TrendReq() gives me the mentioned error.

Thank you a ton, Mario